# Launching a 32-bit explorer on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, shell, windows-explorer

I'm trying to get shell extenions (e.g. unlocker) to work on Windows 7 64 bit.
I found [this post](http://www.sturmnet.org/blog/2008/04/23/32-bit-explorer-on-vista-64) about launching it on Vista 64bit, which doesn't seem to work on Windows 7. There's also [this old post](http://extended64.com/blogs/bhpaddock/archive/2005/05/22/539.aspx), but it doesn't give away the registry key and the exe it links to gives a 404.

Comment: Already on SF http://serverfault.com/questions/8549/running-explorer-as-32-bit-on-windows-7-64-bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Noting *admintech's* comment that this is already answered i.e. it's not possible, the alternate solution is to find 64-bit equivalents of all software you need shell-extensions for. If you would make a list which apps you would like, perhaps we can find 64-bit variations thereof?

As an alternative to your example Unlocker, [Lock Hunter](http://lockhunter.com/) offers identical functionality and has 64-bit + shell extension support i.e. you can right-click on a file and show which processes are locking it.

Answer (score 2):

Unlocker has both 32 & 64-bit versions available.

Download from here: http://cedrick.collomb.perso.sfr.fr/unlocker/

Answer (score 0):

An amusing alternate to consider is some kind of application virtualization tool, like Novell Zenworks Application Virtualization, which is based on the Xenocode product.

This has the ability to even run Internet Explorer 6 on Windows 7!

It tries to bundle all the files and registry settings needed to run the application into a thick binary that runs in its own virtual space on the machine.

Very cute, shockingly effective, but not perfect, as some things just cannot be virtualized in this manner.